# If post exists in the database - each time goes on `else`

Tags: plugins, posts, title

Firstly, I am a newbie when it comes to php. I have a plugin that periodically imports posts into my website. Normally, it should check if the post already exists, and if it does, it updates it. Otherwise it creates a new one. Now for some reason, it always takes the `else` path no matter what.

The `if` is like this:

```
if ( nmp_post_exists( $cam->username ) ) {
```

and the function is:

```
function nmp_post_exists($title) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $title . "'", 'ARRAY_A');
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [`get_page_by_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title), which, despite have `page` in its name, allows you to specify the `post_type` as a parameter (so you can search `post`s as well as any custom post type).

Comment: Is your table prefix `wp_`?

Comment: No, my table prefix is different. That's what I am doing wrong? It's the name of the domain without the .com.

Comment: I am retarded. I am testing as we speak, I think it's my fault. I changed the default prefix for the database, and I wasted a day wondering what is wrong. Shall get back with results asap.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that PHP considers the value of `$wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '" . $title . "'", 'ARRAY_A');` to be true no matter what (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2382490/how-does-true-false-work-in-php)). You'll have to count the number of rows that are returned

Try something like this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = '$title'";
$count = $wpdb->get_var($query);
return $count > 0;
```

Comment: According to the codex the $wpdb->get_row returns "NULL" if nothing is found.

Comment: Kasper, your choice did not work, still going only on the else path. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The code was working fine. My problem was that I forgot that I changed the default prefix of the database. Sorry guys for wasting your time. Have a good one